# Join rest of the elements of an array with the first element

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I'm trying the following logic and not sure which array function can help. I'm not able to use map or es6 but would like to see an answer.

```
I tried the following:
```

/* JS */ - This is not working and would like to see how to make it work.

```
var input = ['x','y','z'];
var powerSetResult = powerSet(input);
console.log(powerSetResult);
/*Ouput should be [''.'x','y','z','xy,'xz','yz','xyz']*/

function powerSet(arr) {
var data = [];
for(var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
 arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[i+1];
 data.push(arr[i]);
}
console.log(data);
return data;
}
```

/* ES 6 */ - Is there a better way to do this?

```
 let input = ['x','y','z'];
 let powerSetResult = powerSet(input);
 console.log(powerSetResult); 
 /*Ouput should be [''.'x','y','z','xy,'xz','yz','xyz']*/

 const powerSet(arr) {
 let data = arr.map(([s1, s2, s3]) => [``,`${s1}`,`${s2}`,`${s3}`,`${s1}${s2}`,`${s1}${s3}`,`${s2}${s3}`,`${s1}${s2}${s3}`]);                                             
 console.log(data);
 return data;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly not the most efficient... but you could do this:

```js
var input = ['x','y','z'];
var powerSetResult = powerSet(input);
console.log(powerSetResult);

function powerSet(arr, result) {
    result = result || new Set();
    const str = arr.join('');
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        for (let j = i; j <= arr.length; j++) {
            result.add(str.slice(i, j));
        }
        powerSet([...arr.slice(0, i), ...arr.slice(i+1)], result)
    }
    return Array.from(result).sort((a, b) => {
        return (a.length - b.length) || a.localeCompare(b);
    });
}
/* Output should be [''.'x','y','z','xy,'xz','yz','xyz'] */
```

Caveat being it will only work for single letter elements, but is easily modifiable to accommodate more.